# Using Kerberos with Webstart. Can´t get tgt from ticket cache

Tags: java, kerberos, java-web-start, principal

I´m having trouble using Kerberos with Webstart.
I want to get the Principal of the current signed on Windows-User and the API tries to get the 
tgt from the ticket cache.

AllowTgtSessionKey  is set in Registry to 1.

With normal Java-application all is ok and I get the ticket and can use the principal.

But when I deploy my Application as Webstart I can´t get the ticket from the cache and get 
LoginException when I call LoginContext#login.

Here´s my code:

Configuration:

```
private static Configuration getProgramaticLoginConfig() 
{
    HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    options.put("useTicketCache", "true"); 
    options.put("doNotPrompt", "true"); 
    options.put("debug","true");                                       
    AppConfigurationEntry krb5LoginModule = new AppConfigurationEntry("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule", LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, options); 
    final AppConfigurationEntry[] aces = new AppConfigurationEntry[]{krb5LoginModule}; 
    Configuration progConfig = new Configuration() 
    { 
      @Override 
      public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String arg0) 
      {                                 
           return aces; 
      } 

    }; 
    return progConfig; 
}
```

And here´s my code:

```
LoginContext lc = null;
    try {
        // create a LoginContext
        lc = new LoginContext("asdjfkasdjkfasdö",new DialogCallbackHandler());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Initialisierung fehlgeschlagen",e);
    }
    try {       
        // login (effectively populating the Subject)
        lc.login();
    } catch(LoginException e) {
        log.error("Login failed",e);
    }
try {
    //get the Subject that represents the signed-on user
    Subject signedOnUserSubject = lc.getSubject();
...
```

What am I doing wrong?
All jars are signed!

Thx for your help.

Regards,
Holger

Answer (score -1):

When you launch an application using web start, it is in an applet context with reduced privileges.

You will need to sign your jar in order to allow jaas logins.

Example here http://www.narendranaidu.com/2007/11/3-easy-steps-to-self-sign-applet-jar.html